ros1_bridge pairs all topics but no data flows in some
I am working on the ridgeback robot of clearpath. I want to use some ros2 nodes so I have make a docker container running ros1_bridge (image ros:foxy-ros1-bridge).
When I use current configuration right after start-up all topics are paired successfully and data flows normally via the ros1_bridge to all the ros2-containers. However, when I launch whichever node of the ros1 navigation stack (let's assume gmapping roslaunch ridgeback_navigation gmapping_demo.launch scan_topic:=scan_merged) even though the new ros1 topics are paired to the appropriate ros2 (I can see them via ros2 topic list in the container), no data flows (e.g the ros2 topic echo /map_metadata doesn't output anything.)
Is there a way to fix this?
Voila the dockerfile I am using for the ros1_bridge:
# ===== environment =====
FROM ros:foxy-ros1-bridge
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENV ROS2_DISTRO="foxy"

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && \
    apt -y upgrade && \
    apt -y install iproute2

RUN apt install -y ros-foxy-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp

ADD fastrtps_profile.xml /fastrtps_profile.xml

# ===== make a bash file to source ROS1 & ROS2 and create the IP_AS_PREFIX environment variable
RUN touch wings_bash.bash && \
    echo "#!/bin/bash" >> /wings_bash.bash && \
    echo "export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=30" >> /wings_bash.bash && \
    echo "source /opt/ros/${ROS2_DISTRO}/setup.bash" >> /wings_bash.bash && \
echo "export FASTRTPS_DEFAULT_PROFILES_FILE=/fastrtps_profile.xml" >> /root/.bashrc && \
echo "export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION='rmw_fastrtps_cpp'" >> /wings_bash.bash && \
# echo "export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION='rmw_cyclonedds_cpp'" >> /wings_bash.bash && \
# ===== add to .bashrc too for interactive shells =====
echo "export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=30" >> /root/.bashrc && \
echo "source /opt/ros/${ROS2_DISTRO}/setup.bash" >> /root/.bashrc && \
    echo "export FASTRTPS_DEFAULT_PROFILES_FILE=/fastrtps_profile.xml" >> /root/.bashrc && \
    echo "export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION='rmw_fastrtps_cpp'" >> /root/.bashrc
    # echo "export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION='rmw_cyclonedds_cpp'" >> /root/.bashrc
    
# COPY ./start.launch.xml /start.launch.xml

CMD source /wings_bash.bash && \
    # ros2 launch start.launch.xml
    # sleep infinity
    # ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge --print-pairs
    ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge --bridge-all-topics

